# how to solve keyboard flickering in React / React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I navigate back using left swipe or programmatically then the navigation is performed first and keyboard hide after leaving the page and it causes keyboard flickering(Keyboard hide and show and then hide again during going back navigation) on iOS. The desire behaviour is to dismiss the keyboard first and then navigate back. My code is given below:

```
const isKeyboardShown = keyboardState?.isKeyboardShown ?? false;

const isKeyboardShownRef = useRef<boolean>(false);
isKeyboardShownRef.current = keyboardState?.isKeyboardShown ?? false;

const keyboardPanResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (_e, gestureState) => {
            const isHorizon = Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > Math.abs(gestureState.dy);

            return isHorizon && isKeyboardShown && shouldDismissKeyboard;
        },
        onPanResponderGrant: Keyboard.dismiss,
    }),
).current;

useEffect(() => {

        const removeSubscription =  navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
                  if (!isKeyboardShownRef.current) {
                      return;
                  }
                  Keyboard.dismiss();

              });

        return () => {

            removeSubscription();
            
        };
  
    }, []);
```

I have spent many days but I am not able to figure out what is wrong. If anyone knows what is the issue then please let me know. Thank you